Reference: Band Limited Hilbert Space
I am studying the mathematical formulation of band-limited functions, specifically those whose Fourier transforms have compact support. I understand that these functions are closely tied to the Paley-Wiener theorem.
For example:
Fix some cutoff frequency $ 0 < a < \infty $ and define the Hilbert space:
$$
H = \{ f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \mid \operatorname{supp}(F) \subset [-a, a] \},
$$
where $ L^2(\mathbb{R}) $ is the set of square-integrable functions, and
$$
F(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-i\omega t} \, dt
$$
is the Fourier transform of $f(\cdot)$. As the inner product, we use:
$$
\langle f, g \rangle_{L^2} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \cdot \overline{g(x)} \, dx.
$$
I would like to dive deeper into the following aspects:

A rigorous description of the Hilbert space of band-limited functions.
How the Paley-Wiener theorem formalizes the relationship between compact frequency support and exponential decay in the time domain.
Examples of functions that illustrate these properties.

Could someone recommend references (textbooks, lecture notes, or research articles) that comprehensively cover these topics, particularly focusing on the Hilbert space structure and decay properties?

Are you looking for a book on Metric Spaces and Functional Analysis?  There are lotsa nice and useful properties of inner-product spaces (Hilbert spaces), but it's kinda mathy.  What DSP thing are you trying to do?  Recognize a symbol buried in noise?

Just a small remark: You'll have a better time studying complex vector spaces with a sesquilinear form if you define the form with conjugate left argument. It makes the notation more intuitive and is the more natural convention.

Hay @Jazzmaniac could you spell out why that's the case?  My Kreyszig book (ca. 1978) conjugates the second (right-hand) argument in its chapter introducing Hilbert spaces. It just seems to me to be a convention. Now, I'm sure you know that sometimes I get on a soapbox ranting about some bad convention regarding some mathematical definition (or a less then "the best" convention).  I think I noticed somewhere that physikers doing QM like conjugating the first argument.  But I never really knew what's behind it.

This seems to speak to it a little but it just pushes the definition of convention onto Paul Dirac.  Why is linearity in the second argument (which requires conjugate linearity in the first argument) a better property than linearity in the first argument (which then requires conjugate linearity in the second argument)?

I think the reason is that (particularly with the bra-ket notation) the argument on the left is normally used as an operator and the argument on the right is the vector or data that the operator is operating on.  So the Fourier Transform can be thought of as the inner product of a complex sinusoid with a signal.  $$ \big\langle e^{i \omega t},, x(t) \big\rangle = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i \omega t} , x(t) , \mathrm{d}t $$ This depicts what the argument, $x(t)$, has in common with the sinusoid $e^{i \omega t}$.

If before diving into the mathematical literature you'd like to review some relevant signal processing literature, I'd recommend the books by Martin Vetterli, specifically Foundations of Signal Processing, which can be legally downloaded from here.
I would also look into A Foundation In Digital Communication by A. Lapidoth. You might not be interested in everything that's in the book, but the first six chapters are definitely relevant for you. In chapter 6 he discusses the Paley-Wiener theorem and its relation to band-limited functions.
